# NVM: node versions install, but then can't be used

Tags: node.js, nvm

I've got NVM installed via homebrew, and I can execute an installation command just fine:

```
nvm install v5
Downloading https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.0.0/node-v5.0.0-darwin-x64.tar.xz...
######################################################################## 100.0%
WARNING: checksums are currently disabled for node.js v4.0 and later
```

But when I attempt to do `nvm use v5`, I get:

```
N/A: version "v5.0.0" is not yet installed
```

This occurs whether or not I make an alias for v5.  I've uninstalled nvm, cleared out/re-added references in my dotfiles, etc.

Comment: did it create `~/.nvm/v5.0.0/`?

Comment: It created `~/.nvm/versions/node/v5.0.0`

Comment: It works okay for me, though I've got nvm installed from the shell script. Perhaps try the nvm shell install (distasteful though it may be) and try again?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the native shell script to work, so I just ended up installing n instead (https://github.com/tj/n)